# Is it possible to convert [int, bool ,float] to ['int', 'bool','float'] with one single line command?

Tags: python

I convert  [int, bool ,float] to ['int', 'bool','float'] using many lines of command.

```
Numbers = [int, bool, float]
>>> [ i for i in Numbers]
[<class 'int'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'float'>]
>>>foo = [ str(i) for i in Numbers]
>>>foo
["<class 'int'>", "<class 'bool'>", "<class 'float'>"]
>>> bar = [ i.replace('<class ','') for i in foo]
>>> bar
["'int'>", "'bool'>", "'float'>"]
>>> baz = [i.replace('>','') for i in bar]
>>> baz
["'int'", "'bool'", "'float'"]
>>> [ eval(i) for i in baz]
['int', 'bool', 'float']
```

How to accomplish such a task in an elegant manner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) attribute.

```
[i.__name__ for i in Numbers]
```

As an aside, if you are interested in performing introspection on Python data structures, use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). For example, `dir(int)` will return a list of all attributes and callable methods you can use on the `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
Numbers = [int, bool ,float] 
Labels = [x.__name__ for x in Numbers]
```

see : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions for further explanation.

Comment: Why and how does this solve the problem? (E.g. What is a comprehension? Where do the docs talk about that?) Those who can answer those questions for themselves don't need someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more pythonic way to do this but a 1-liner that works for these types is:

```
>>> [ x.__name__ for x in Numbers ]
['int', 'bool', 'float']
```

Btw you can find out attributes an object has using [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

For example:

```
>>> dir(Numbers[0])
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
__name__ will help you to show type of it as a string,
```

you can find available modules for variables and function using `dir(var)`

```
>>> num = [1,bool(1),1.10]
>>> [type(i).__name__ for i in num] 
['int', 'bool', 'float']
>>>
```